# Verilog/SystemVerilog: "constant" function is considered non-constant

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, yosys, verilator

I have a Module which has a port whos width should depend on a value from a function:
(Syntax is Verilog/Systemverilog mixed as i am using yosys for synthesis, which only supports a limited amount of SV)

```
module MY_MODULE#(
    parameter MY_PARAM = 2,
    parameter PARAM_TWO = 10
)(
    input logic CLK_CI,
    ...
    input logic [myfunc(MY_PARAM, PARAM_TWO):0] RND,
    ...
    output logic Finish_SO
);
```

The problem is that the function needs to calculate the value using a for loop, as i need the sum some calculated values. Example:

```
function automatic int myfunc(input loop_control, input variables);
    int carry;
    int variables_next = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < loop_control; i++) begin
        carry = variables_next & 1;
        variables_next = (variables_next >> 1) + carry;
    end
    myfunc = carry;
endfunction
```

Technically, the output of the function is constant as long as the inputs are constant. In my case, i always call the function with localparams, which are constant. However as i am using a for loop and the carry variable changes, it is considered non-constant.

Error from verilator:
Expecting expression to be constant, but can't determine constant for FUNCREF 'myfunc'

Error from yosys:
Non-constant function call in constant expression.

Is there a way to have a function with a for loop as a constant function?

I could hardcode the values in a parameter array, however i would prefer to not do that.

I wanted to create a function which uses constant (localparams) inputs to create outputs which can be used with port definition. One approach i have tried was to get the values i needed within the generate for loop i have, however i have not found a way to add up the localparams in the generate for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try precalculate your parameter as follows

```
module MY_MODULE#(
    parameter MY_PARAM = 2,
    parameter PARAM_TWO = 10,
    localparam my_func_data = my_func(MY_PARAM, PARAM_TWO)
)(
    input logic CLK_CI,
    input logic [my_func_data:0] RND,
    output logic Finish_SO
);

function automatic int my_func(input loop_control, input variables);
    int carry;
    int variables_next = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < loop_control; i++) begin
        carry = variables_next & 1;
        variables_next = (variables_next >> 1) + carry;
    end
    my_func = carry;
endfunction

endmodule
```

Alternatively, you can declare `my_func_data` as a parameter to be able to modify it externally.

Another reason why Vivado, in my case, is also throwing an warning in your construction is that your function is named `myfunc`, but you are trying to call `my_func`. The first error raised in such a case is 'range must be bounded by constant expressions', and the second one is 'my_func' is not declared'.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought it would make a difference as a module parameter, but now both tools see it as a constant function and that is what i needed. 
I also edited the code to fix the my_func myfunc typo.

Comment: Also mind that i tried to assign it to a localparam, which did not work.